# Springcloud data flow stream with http-request post

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy a springcloud data flow stream like this:

```
time | http-request --http-method-expression='POST' --url-expression='http://mydomain.fake/myservice?myparams=myvalues'  | log
```

The stream deploy without errors, but when I check the http-request log I can see a exception. Obviously, the stream not works

> Property or field 'POST' cannot be found on object of
> type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage'

I checked the [HttpRequestFunctionProperties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/main/functions/function/http-request-function/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/fn/http/request/HttpRequestFunctionProperties.java) class from github, but I didn't get any clue about my fault.

Any help please?

Update 1:

I get it. It works with `--http-method-expression=new String('POST')` BUT only when the stream is **updated** . I cant **deploy** the stream directly with this param ...

Thanks !!!

Comment: Try `'''POST'''`.

Comment: or `--http-method-expression="'POST'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the SpEL parser is interpreting `POST` as a field on the Message (the default evaluation context). The expression `'POST'` is not being parsed correctly as a literal string. This is most likely due to some escaping problem. Try what Gary suggests.